# find files with glob pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, find

I need to find files in a folder which match a string like this:

Say I have:

```
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.3.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.44.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I would like to be able to run something like

```
find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name 'vim*'
```

And it should only return the lines which have 'vim', at the moment I get vim-runtime too obviously because of -name 'vim*'

I need to use glob patterns.

here is the format of everything:

```
cachedir               package     packageVersion packageRelease architecture extesnion
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ vim-runtime 7.3.754        1              x86_64       pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ vim         7.3.918        2              x86_64       pkg.tar.xz
```

So basically I need to find an exact package using the command 'find'

Comment: Q: `I need to find an exact package using find`  A: `Specify the exact package to find`

Comment: have you _anything_ tried?

Comment: I dont understand either of the above comments

Comment: I see. so I will vote for close here. good luck.

Comment: Another quick solution could be pipe the output to grep and filter using a regex from there `find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name 'vim*' | grep [regex]`

Comment: got this: find /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ -name 'vim-[any character except hyphen]-[0-9]-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz'

Comment: @Endoro, obviously he's tried. C'mon man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to find vim-*.gz but not vim-runtime*.gz. If that's right than please make the question clearer. the answer would then be:

regex is the wrong track. finds -name option doesn't use regex. it uses file glob patterns, like the ones you specifiy on command line. try

```
find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name 'vim-[0-9]*.gz'
```

edit: `vim-[0-9]*` is not good because it finds packages that have a number in the package name. but what about this?

```
find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name 'vim-*-*-*.pkg.tar.xz'
```

edit:
sorry, my fault. doesnn't work because `*` matches `runtime-7.3.754`.
Maybe the regex idea was better than I thought (didn't know the -regex option).
how about this?

```
find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -regex '.*/vim-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*.pkg.tar.xz'
```

Comment: yes thats what Im onto, I have 'find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name "packageName-packageVersion-packageRelease-architecture-extension"' so far

Comment: find /var/cache/pacman/pkg -name 'vim-*-*-*.pkg.tar.xz' still picks up /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

Comment: I am here now: find /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ -name 'vim-[not hyphen]-[0-9]-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz', I just cant find a way to say 'not hyphen'

Comment: see my answer. `[^-]` is 'not hyphen'. `[^-]` works as a glob pattern, too, but only for a single character. in glob patterns `*` doesn't multiply the preceding item like in regex.

Comment: Thanks, thats done it. Any idea how to do it with globs though? But I think I will mark this is the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To turn `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` into

```
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ vim-runtime 7.3.754        1              x86_64       pkg.tar.xz
```

you can use:

```
files=(
    /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz 
    /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.3.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
    /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.44.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $f =~ ^(.*/)(.*)-([^-]+)-([0-9])-([^.]+)\.(.*) ]]; then 
        for i in "${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do 
            echo "$i => ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
        done
    fi      
done
```

This outputs

```
0 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
1 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
2 => vim-runtime
3 => 7.3.754
4 => 1
5 => x86_64
6 => pkg.tar.xz
0 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.3.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
1 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
2 => vim
3 => 7.3.918
4 => 2
5 => x86_64
6 => pkg.tar.xz
0 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.44.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
1 => /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
2 => vim
3 => 7.44.918
4 => 2
5 => x86_64
6 => pkg.tar.xz
```

You would probably want `for f in /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*; do`

Comment: This is useful, I guess I could use this to get a solution to my problem. But it would be nice to use "find /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ -name 'vim-[not hyphen]-[0-9]-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz'", I just cant find a way to say 'not hyphen' with globs. Thanks

Comment: bash has extended globs: `shopt -s extglob` Then "not-hyphen" is `+([^-])`. I don't suppose that translates to find's glob patterns

Answer (score 0):

### Use module `glob`

#### Import necessary modules

```
    import pandas as pd
    import glob
```

#### Write the pattern: `pattern`

```
    pattern = 'uber*'
```

#### Save all file matches: csv_files

```
    uber_files = glob.glob(pattern)
```

#### Print the file names

```
    print(uber_files)
```

Output:

```
['uber-raw-data-2014_05.csv', 'uber-raw-data-2014_04.csv', 'uber-raw-data-2014_06.csv']
```